# Any way to organize images into folders in Wagtail CMS?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to use Wagtail, the Django CMS. The images uploaded via the admin interface all go to the same place and it seems there is no way to organize images except by tagging them. Is there any way to organize them into folders or to search for them by date uploaded?

Furthermore, the search function for the images at least on the Wagtail demo installation, does not pull up any results if searching by the tag name (it does work with the search term in the title field).

Any suggestions for how to organize images in Wagtail would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wagtail 1.4 introduced the concept of [Collections](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.4.1/releases/1.4.html#collections-for-image-document-organisation) which was their way of address this need:

> Images and documents can now be organised into collections, set up by
>   administrators through the Settings -> Collections menu item. User
>   permissions can be set either globally (on the ‘Root’ collection) or
>   on individual collections, allowing different user groups to keep
>   their media items separated.

Don't think you can search by tag though...

Comment: Searching by tag works better if you have ElasticSearch configured: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.4.5/topics/search/backends.html#elasticsearch-backend

Answer (score 1):

If you need more than a flat folder structure, there is also this project:

https://github.com/anteatersa/Wagtail-Image-Folders

which is a replacement for the built-in `wagtailimages` app. I haven't tried it myself though.